# How to use PowerShell and robocopy to backup files to a server?

Tags: powershell, backup, robocopy

I am just starting with PowerShell, so please be kind.

All I want to do is backup my directories and files from my laptop to the desktop computer, i.e. "server",  using PowerShell and robocopy. I am the administrator to both machines (Windows 7).

This fails with ***access denied*** on the "server", i.e., desktop, despite the permissions being set for "Everybody" to do everything.

Any help (or better way) is really appreciated! Thanks.

```
$cred=get-credential

$sourcepath = ("\\localhost\C$\nova5");
$TargetPath = ("\\library\E$\nova5");


New-PSDrive -Name source -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $SourcePath 
New-PSDrive -Name target -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $TargetPath -Credential $cred

robocopy source target /e;

return;
```

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57994446/1322112

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Psdrive is a feature for powershell cmdlet not for extrrnal command , change this line:

```
robocopy "\\localhost\C$\nova5" "$TargetPath" /e
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between \\localhost\C$ and \\localhost\C -- no "$" ??? robocopy does not seem to handle C$.

Comment: The trick here is to use the original UNC path(s) for Robocopy, and it will still somehow use the credentials "stored" in the session by `New-PSDrive`. Somewhat hackish, but still cleaner and more secure this way than using `New-PSDrive -Name 'X' -Persist ...` or `net use X: ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$cred=get-credential

$sourcepath = C:\nova5 ;
$TargetPath = "\\library\E$\nova5"

New-PSDrive -Name target -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $TargetPath -Credential $cred

.\robocopy.exe $source $target "/e"
```