# Robocopy with PowerShell : ERROR 3 (0x00000003) The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, robocopy

I have a PowerShell script for backup that I used on Windows 2003 Server for a long time, and now I have a problem with it on Windows Server 2012 R2. I have this message when I try to execute it:

> 2019/09/18 08:40:25 ERROR 3 (0x00000003) Creating Destination Directory Z:\BACKUP\D\ The system cannot find the path specified.

I run the PowerShell script in PowerShell ISE as administrator or as a scheduled task with highest privileges. The script is executing on a server on a domain (DOMAIN1) that has the source drive and the destination is on another server on another domain (DOMAIN2). There is no trust between the domains.

When I use the `net use` command it works fine with PowerShell ISE but not via scheduled task. When I use `New-PSDrive` it doesn't work anywhere. I insert `GCI` statement to be sure the drive is connected and it lists the content of the destination directory.

I simplified the code for debugging:

```
$strNetDrvPath   = '\\server.domain2.local\BkpDrv'
$strNetDrvUser   = 'DOMAIN2\BkpUser'
$strNetDrvPwd    = 'ABCD1234'

#net use Z: $strNetDrvPath /user:$strNetDrvUser $strNetDrvPwd
$objCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential -ArgumentList $strNetDrvUser, ($strNetDrvPwd|ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
New-PSDrive –Name Z –PSProvider FileSystem –Root $strNetDrvPath -Credential $objCredential

gci Z: -Name

$strCmd = "robocopy D:\. Z:\BACKUP\D /B /MIR /NP /R:0 /LOG:D:\RC_Log.txt"
Invoke-Expression $strCmd
#cmd /c $strCmd

#net use Z: /delete /y
Remove-PSDrive Z
```

I left a comment with the `net use` command to show what I tried. What could be the problem? Is there a another way to do it that should work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to use `New-PSDrive` for mapping a Windows network drive you need to add the parameter `-Persist`. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-3.0):

> **`-Persist`**
>
> Indicates that this cmdlet creates a Windows mapped network drive. Mapped network drives are saved in Windows on the local computer. They are persistent, not session-specific, and can be viewed and managed in File Explorer and other tools.

```
New-PSDrive –Name Z –PSProvider FileSystem –Root $strNetDrvPath -Persist -Credential $objCredential
```

Since you provide explicit credentials `net use` should work just fine from a scheduled task. If it doesn't something else is amiss (for debugging scheduled tasks [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41635982/1630171)).

Also, **[DO NOT USE `Invoke-Expression`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)**. `robocopy` can be run directly from PowerShell.

```
$params = '/B', '/MIR', '/NP', '/R:0', '/LOG:D:\RC_Log.txt'
& robocopy D:\. Z:\BACKUP\D @params
```

Comment: Thank you! it work in all case. I didn't test it with NET USE but probably we have to use the /persistent:yes to make it work

Comment: I found there's no need to specify `-Persist`. Instead, simplify specify the original UNC destination path in Robocopy. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26396442/1322112